# Drop Down Menu disappears when you move your mouse down to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Dreamweaver CS6 to [help an organization set up their website](http://www.mtwildbison.org/). To save time on the menu bar, [I used one at Menu Maker](https://app.cssmenumaker.com/?theme_id=11). It was a wee bit wider than I wanted with my menu buttons, but I went in and manually reduced the padding so that they all fit on the menu bar, as well as increasing the font. The drop down menus worked great at the site preview, but when I inserted all the html code where I wanted the bar, copied the script.js and the styles.css it into the files folder, the drop down menus disappear when you move your mouse cursor down to select one.

After having difficulty, I submitted a support ticket. I then did some searches and saw complaints by other users that there is no support, no contact.

I have tried to ascertain where the coding issue is, that is causing the drop down menu to disappear, am now going blind in code view. ;( I could really use and would appreciate some advice.

HTML

```
<div id="cssmenu"> 
          <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> 
              Home</a></li>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="about.htm"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> 
              About Us</a> 
              <ul>
                <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="org.htm">Organization</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="mission.htm">Our Wild Bison Mission</a> 
              <ul>
                <li><a href="rationale.htm">Rationale</a></li>
                <li><a href="mtplans.htm">Montana Plans for Wild Bison</a></li>
                <li><a href="wood.htm">Wood Bison Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="supporters.htm">Supporters</a></li>
                <li><a href="polls.htm">Polls</a></li>
                <li><a href="fwpdocs.htm">FWP Documents</a></li>
                <li><a href="scientists.htm">Scientist's Letter of Support</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="wildness.htm">Why Wildness?</a> 
              <ul>
                <li><a href="biodef.htm">Biological Definitions</a></li>
                <li><a href="legaldef.htm">Legal Definitions</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="legal.htm">Legal Issues</a> 
              <ul>
                <li><a href="wbandlaw.htm">Wild Bison and the Law</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="habitat.htm">CMR/APR Bison Habitat</a> 
              <ul>
                <li><a href="cmr.htm">CMR</a></li>
                <li><a href="apr.htm">APR</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://mtwildbison.blogspot.com/">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="contribute.htm">Contribute</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Java

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="menu-button">Menu</div>');
  $('#cssmenu #menu-button').on('click', function(){
    var menu = $(this).next('ul');
    if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
      menu.removeClass('open');
    } else {
      menu.addClass('open');
    }
});

});
})(jQuery);
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button , 
#cssmenu{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul:after , 
#cssmenu:after{
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 1102px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #d5d69e;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dedfb4 0%, #c9ca81 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #dedfb4), color-stop(100%, #c9ca81));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dedfb4 0%, #c9ca81 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #dedfb4 0%, #c9ca81 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dedfb4 0%, #c9ca81 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dedfb4 0%, #c9ca81 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul {
    background: url('images/bg.png');
    box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.12);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #515223;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 19px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #d0d193;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
    padding-right: 40px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #515223;
  right: 17px;
  top: 20.5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  top: -4px;
  left: 20px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  top: 11px;
  left: -4px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul::after {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  left: auto;
  right: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  top: 120px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  top: 49px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 6px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  padding-right: 6px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: 180px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 11px 25px;
  width: 180px;
  color: #777777;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #777777;
  right: 17px;
  top: 14px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #777777;
  right: auto;
  left: 17px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-left-color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-right-color: #333333;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    background: #d5d69e;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul.open {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li,
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    padding: 18px 25px 18px 25px;
    border-right: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #515223;
    padding: 18px 25px 18px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: url('images/bg.png');
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 45px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::after {
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #515223;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #515223;
    right: 25px;
    top: 18px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #515223;
    right: 25px;
    top: 28px;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). No one can help you if you do not provide code.

Comment: I can see that you have made a greate effort getting that menubar as it is. But it might be a good idea to look into bootstrap for getting your menu to work. The problem with the menu disappearing is due to that mouse hover over a "white space" when you try to move it down to the dropdown. You will get into trouble later when you try to make it work on mobile. Try looking in to bootsrap is my best advice.

Comment: @user3126099, are you able to reproduce the menu in something like https://jsfiddle.net so that the community can help debug the issue?

Comment: Apologize for missing the code with initial post, added it in.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the gap between your menu and the submenu is causing the menu button to lose it's `hover` state when the mouse moves towards the submenu.

The easiest solution would be to adjust the `top` property of the submenu to remove the gap. Try adding this to the very bottom of your `styles.css` file:

```css
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > ul {
    top: 37px;
}
```

Edit:

A better solution would be to use hover intent to delay the closing of the submenu so that the user has enough time to move the pointer to it's intended location

Comment: Tried the top property adjustment code at the bottom, and then after line 98 which has that same code,  neither worked.